# The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, antiforgerytoken

here is another hurdle for me, I want my site to remain cross-site attacks protected, I'm developing a Master/Detail form by using asp.net mvc 5 through Ajax request, So, in order to create one entry, I've to go through the process of Ajax Request, this way :

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/Sales/Create',
        data: JSON.stringify(salesmain),
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json;',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {

            if (result.Success == "1") {
                window.location.href = "/Sales/index";
            }
            else {
                alert(result.ex);
            }
        }
    });
```

now, it is not navigating to the Create action in the Sales Controller, as the ajax request says, and before that, it throws the following exception :

> The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.

I've searched a lot on google but still unsuccessful, that's why I'm here, I've read some blogs which says fetch the hidden __RequestVerificationToken field using jquery and append it to the form values, enclosing the JSON.stringify(salesmain) in a function, this way :

```
$.ajax({
.
.
addRequestVerificationToken(JSON.stringify(salesmain))
```

and the function :

```
function addRequestVerificationToken(data) {
data.__RequestVerificationToken = $('input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();
return data;
};
```

Plus, I already have below code structure :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
  .
  .
```

and the attribute before the Create action :

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public JsonResult Create([Bind(Include = "SalesId,ReferenceNo,SalesDate,SalesPerson")] SalesMain salesMain)
{
.
.
```

and also I'm using jQuery 1.5, may be it is the culprit, if not then what should I do to resolve this issue? Any HELP will be deeply appreciated, Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: What is `salesmain` (in `data: JSON.stringify(salesmain),`)? Why are you not just using `data: $('form').serialize()` to serialize your form including the token?

Comment: Sir, salesmain is a javascript variable here is how I declared it before getting its values from the form : `var salesmain = { "SalesId": "", "ReferenceNo": "", "SalesDate": "", "SalesPerson": "", "SalesSubs": [] };`

Comment: But if you have a form (and you have generated the view correctly), then just use `data: $('form').serialize()` and remove the `contentType: 'application/json;',` But why on earth are you using ajax when you just redirecting using `window.location.href = "/Sales/index";`?

Comment: Awesome, I removed `contentType: 'application/json'`, and the error's gone, Can you please explain it a bit by answering it below, I wanna mark it as the answer. Actually, it feels gracious when I meet some experienced People.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your `addRequestVerificationToken()` function does not add the token because you have already stringified the data (its no longer a javascript object so `data.__RequestVerificationToken = $(...)` does nothing).

You could make this work by changing the code to

```
data: JSON.stringify(addRequestVerificationToken(salesmain)),
```

however this is unnecessary as you do not need to stringify the data. Instead remove the `contentType: 'application/json;',` option so that it uses the default `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'` and use

```
data: addRequestVerificationToken(salesmain),
```

or better still, if you have correctly generated you view using the `HtmlHelper` methods and your inputs contain the correct name attribute (`name="SalesId"`, `name="ReferenceNo"` etc) then you an simply use

```
data: $('form').serialize(),`
```

which will correctly serialize all inputs in your form including the token.

Comment: You seriously Rock, Thank you so much :)

Comment: I have been looking for a solution since yesterday. No matter what I did 'appliation/json' did not solve the problem for me.  However 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' was perfect remedy. Thanks tons.